# ES6のクラス内メソッドをスコープ外に定義したい

Tags: javascript

```
class Test {
  foo() {

  }
  bar() {

  }
  ...
}
```

クラス内のメソッド1つ1つの記述量が多くなった際、クラス内で関数の宣言だけ行い、スコープ外に定義することはできますか？

```
class Test {
  foo()
  bar()
}

Test.foo = { .. }
Test.bar = { .. }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロトタイプにメソッドを定義すればよいと思います。

```
class Test {}

Test.prototype.foo = () => { ... }
Test.prototype.bar = () => { ... }
```

宣言にはあまり意味がありません。プロトタイプが上書きされるためです。
例えば引数の数などが異なってもエラー等にはなりません。